# Quantising classical harmonic oscillator like classical fields

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, harmonic-oscillator, classical-field-theory

Iam studying QFT, 
But Iam stucked at catching the mathematical formulae for harmonic oscillator  analogue in QFT,
For a classical harmonic oscillator I can write

$x(t)= Ae^{i\omega t} +A^{\dagger} e^{-i\omega t} $

this gives

$P(t)=mi\omega (Ae^{i\omega t} -A ^{\dagger} e^{-i\omega t}) $

On quantizing position and momentum we get

$\hat x(t)= \hat Ae^{i\omega t} +\hat A^{\dagger} e^{-i\omega t} $

and

$\hat p(t)=mi\omega (\hat Ae^{i\omega t} -\hat A^{\dagger}e^{-i\omega t}) $
 Using the commutation relation of position and momentum, we get

$[x (t),p (t)]=i\hbar$

this gives

$[\hat A^{\dagger},\hat A ]={{\hbar} \over {2\omega m }}$

What I do above is the same analogue that we do in Quantization of free fields. But we know that in harmonic oscillator the ladder operators obey the commutation relation

$[\hat a,\hat a^{\dagger} ]=1$ 
Corresponding analogue in  QFT is

$[\hat a(k),\hat a^{\dagger}(k') ]=\delta^3 (k-k')$

My question is why don't we get the above standard results on quantizing classical harmonic oscillator  equation like we quantize classical fields?

Comment: Your definition of $\hat{x}$ is wrong.

Comment: Is your question about the delta function vs 1?

Comment: Can you write correct definition for $\hat x $ @aitfel

Comment: No,  my question is about $[\hat A^{\dagger},\hat A ]={{\hbar} \over {2\omega m }}$ vs   
$[\hat a,\hat a^{\dagger} ]=1$  @Qmechanic

Comment: That's just a different normalization.

Comment: Can you clarify,  how can those 2 commutators be equal @Qmechanic